# Is there a word for tautology in probability.

Tags: probability

Im wondering if there is a word that describes an event that will always happen like a tautology in logic.

Such as, the event

D which is the probability that it will snow on the weekend if it snows on Saturday.

Comment: I think you're looking for a _sure_ event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If something always happens, we say it is a "sure event".

Slightly weaker than that is if the probability is $1$, we say it happens [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely). Note that this doesn't mean it will necessarily *always* happen, but that it's probability is 1. For a finite sample space, there is no difference, but if you are familiar with measure theory "almost surely" has analogous meaning to "almost everywhere" and "almost never" is analogous to "on a set of measure zero".